# Finding $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\prod_{k=1}^n(2k-1)}{(2n)^n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, products

Recently got this on a test:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\prod_{k=1}^n(2k-1)}{(2n)^n}$$

Because it's a freshman calculus course, I think we were expected to solve it like a physicist. Taking a look at the first few terms of the series:

$$\{\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{16},\frac{5}{216},\cdots\}$$And saying "this probably converges at $0$". Because this is all that's been covered in our text so far. I find this really sketchy, considering how carefully we normally tiptoe around infinities. What would be a more robust solution of this problem?

**Edit**

Sorry, the question in the title was different from the one here. Fixed.

**Attempted solution by ratio test**

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{3\cdot5\cdot7\cdot\cdots\cdot(n-1)\cdot n\cdot(n+1)}{(2n+2)^n(2n+2)}}{\frac{3\cdot5\cdot7\cdot\cdots\cdot(n-1)\cdot n}{(2n)^n}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2^nn^n(n+1)}{(2n+2)^{(n+1)}}$$Both the top and the bottom have a largest term of $n^{n+1}$, but at the bottom there is a coefficient of $2^{n+1}$, so the series converges.

Is this good reasoning?

Comment: You could use the "ratio test". Certainly, if the associated series converges, then the sequence must converge to $0$.

Comment: By ratio test you mean $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|$?

Comment: Exactly. You can show in this case $|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}|\to 0$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I've written up a solution by ratio test. I'm not sure if it's correct. Do you mind checking?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$
\frac{\prod_{k=1}^n(2\,k-1)}{(2\,n)^n}=\frac{1}{2\,n}\cdot\frac{3}{2\,n}\cdot\dots\cdot\frac{2\,n-1}{2\,n}<\frac{1}{2\,n}.
$$

Comment: Wow, this solution escaped me. Very good solution. I can't believe I missed it.

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite the product as

$$\prod_{k=1}^n (2 k-1) = \frac{(2 n)!}{2^n n!}$$

Then use the [Stirling approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation)

$$n! \sim n^n e^{-n} \sqrt{2 \pi n} \quad (n \to \infty)$$

to deduce that the asymptotic behavior of the ratio, which is

$$\frac{(2 n)!}{2^{2 n} n!\, n^n}$$

behaves as $\sqrt{2} e^{-n}$ as $n \to \infty$.  Therefore, the limit is zero.